# Symfony Nested Validation Constraints

Tags: php, validation, constraints, symfony

I came accross curious problem. Lets say we want to validate some id. Validation should pass 10 different conditions(constraints) and we have to do it in 10 different places. I thought I can save myself writing unnessecary code by nesting one validation in another.

Here's what I did:

- I've created new, custom validation constraint called IdParameter
- I've registered IdParameterValidator.php file as service and injected validator service to it
- I've put there another validation process(in our example 10 constraints which I will have to use in 10 different places) - I used Constraints\Collection to do it, so it looks kinda like this:

  ```
  <?php

  namespace Awesome\BlogBundle\Validator\Constraints;

  use Symfony\Component\Validator;

  class IdParameterValidator extends Validator\ConstraintValidator
  {
      private $_data = array();
      private $_validator;


  public function __construct(Validator\Validator\RecursiveValidator $validator)
  {
      $this->_validator = $validator;
  }

  public function validate($value, Validator\Constraint $constraint)
  {
      /* Preparing object of constraints */
      $postIDConstraints = new Validator\Constraints\Collection(array(
          'postId' => array(
              new Validator\Constraints\Type(array(
                  'type' => 'integer',
                  'message' => 'This ain\'t no integer man!'
              )),
              new Validator\Constraints\Range(array(
                  'min' => 1,
                  'minMessage' => 'Post id is not valid'
              ))
          )
      ));

      /* Validating ID */
      $this->_data['errors'] = $this->_validator->validate(array('postId' => $value), $postIDConstraints);

      /* Checking validation result */
      if(count($this->_data['errors']) > 0) {
          $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)->addViolation();
      }
    }
  }
  ```

So now I can use  as many constraint as I whish and still have a clean service code:

```
$postIDConstraints = new Validator\Constraints\Collection(array(
    'postId' => array(
         new myValidator\Constraints\IdParameter()
     )
 ));

 /* Validating postID */
 $this->_data['errors'] = $this->_validator->validate(array('postId' => (int)$postID), $postIDConstraints);
```

I'm wondering if it's correct approach?

Best Regards,
R.

P.S
I always comment my code - I didn't put comments here to keep it clean.